# Brecht's Life of Galileo and the need for hero

Tags: german-language, bertolt-brecht, life-of-galileo

Regarding Brecht's play *The life of Galileo*.

There is a part where Andrea says 'unhappy the land that has no heroes'

and Galileo says 'No, unhappy the land that needs heroes'

Can you make reference to the play and explain which one of these statements does Brecht himself side with?